# Conditional Inference trees on correlated observations

Tags: r, classification, cart

I have a dataset containing a binary response variable and a few numeric predictor variables. I would like to use Conditional Inference Trees algorithm in R using the ctree function in party package.

However, the outcomes in the dataset are correlated because a single individual is contributing to more than one record in this data.

Is there an underlying assumption of independence in ctree that may prevent the use of this technique on my dataset? If so, are there any standard techniques by which I can get around this?

Please note that I am using GEE (PROC GENMOD in SAS with the REPEATED option) as one of the modeling options. I would like to also provide an alternative solution using a tree-based approach and I would definitely prefer to use Conditional Inference Trees over CART of CHAID, if possible.

Thanks.

- KC